# want to reach my username but snapshot.data!['username'] doesnt work

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this line i get an error:

snapshot.data!['username']

Error message:
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'

In the turotorial I follows this gets you the username in Firebase but it doesnt work since the updates. How do I do to reach the username?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble(
    this.message,
    this.userId,
    this.isMe, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String message;
  final String userId;
  final bool isMe;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isMe
                ? Color.fromARGB(210, 23, 163, 13)
                : Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 36, 66),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              topRight: Radius.circular(12),
              bottomLeft: !isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(12),
              bottomRight: !isMe ? Radius.circular(12) : Radius.circular(0),
            ),
          ),
          width: 140,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 10,
            horizontal: 16,
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder<Object>(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(userId)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text('Loading...');
                    }

                    return Text(
                      snapshot.data!['username'], <----------------THE ERROR
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    );
                  }),
              Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that's because you're using FutureBuilder<Object> use FutureBuilder<Map> instead

Comment: ok but when i do that the line right below gets a waring in the call to FirebaseFirestore.instance: "The argument type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>?"

Comment: yes sorry it should be FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map>>